# Как получить число из названия месяца с помощью datetime.strptime()?

Tags: python, datetime

Всем привет! Моя главная задача - найти разницу в секундах двух разных времен. Но проблема в том что в `input` надо написать месяц на `str` и с `output` получить число. Например:
`input`:
10 `<- Дни` Dec `<- месяц December` 2020 `<- Год`
11 `<- Дни` Dec `<- месяц December` 2021 `<- Год`
`output`:
31622400 `это секунды`
Код:

```py
def time_delta(t1, t2):
    daydlt = int(t1[1]) - int(t2[1])*24*3600
    montdlt = None# Проблема вот 
    
t1 = list(input().split())
t2 = list(input().split())
time_delta(t1, t2)
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec", "%b").month` -> `12`

Comment: Эти `<- ` присутствуют в вводе? Если нет, то лучше уберите из примера, т.к. путает

Comment: Я ж их специально написал чтобы поняли что это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вводимые строки с датами можно распарсить через модуль `datetime` и получить разницу в секундах

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT

date1 = DT.datetime.strptime('10 Dec 2020', '%d %b %Y')
date2 = DT.datetime.strptime('11 Dec 2021', '%d %b %Y')

total_seconds = int((date1 - date2).total_seconds())
print(total_seconds)
# -31622400

print(abs(total_seconds))
# 31622400
```

Если считывать ввод:

```
...
date1 = DT.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d %b %Y')
date2 = DT.datetime.strptime(input(), '%d %b %Y')
...
```